# Tag duplicates in pandas with serial number

Tags: python, pandas, database, duplicates, data-analysis

I am currently facing a problem with a large database. The database contains rows with information about customers, like their first names, dates of birth, tax IDs etc.  The database is structured as follows:

| CustomerID | FirstName | LastName | DoB | VAT Number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Nick | Jones | 12/1/1982 | 222987432 |
| 2 | John | Smith | 3/20/1997 | 167459022 |
| 3 | Nick | Jones | 12/27/1999 | 169986555 |
| 4 | Nick | Jones | 12/1/1982 | 222987432 |
| 5 | Anne | Johnson | 1/17/1969 | 222987432 |
| 6 | JOHN | SMITH | 3/20/1997 | 999999999 |
| 7 | John | Smith | 3/20/1997 | 999999999 |
| 8 | Anne | Johnson | 1/17/1969 | 128347562 |
| 9 | Nick | Jones | 12/1/1982 | 567829415 |
| 10 | Timothy | Davids | 5/27/2001 | 457891064 |

I would like to make a Python function (we use Pandas to manipulate the excel file), that will create a column that will assign a unique serial number to all duplicates. The rule is as follows: if two entries have the same first name and last name, and either the same DoB or VAT number (is there a way to add conditional statements or logical operators to the groupby Pandas function?). The final database should look like this:

| CustomerID | FirstName | LastName | DoB | VAT Number | S/N |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Nick | Jones | 12/1/1982 | 222987432 | 1 |
| 2 | John | Smith | 3/20/1997 | 167459022 | 2 |
| 3 | Nick | Jones | 12/27/1999 | 169986555 | 1 |
| 4 | Nick | Jones | 12/1/1982 | 222987432 | 1 |
| 5 | Anne | Johnson | 1/17/1969 | 222987432 | 3 |
| 6 | JOHN | SMITH | 3/20/1997 | 999999999 | 4 |
| 7 | John | Smith | 3/20/1997 | 999999999 | 2 |
| 8 | Anne | Johnson | 1/17/1969 | 128347562 | 3 |
| 9 | Nick | Jones | 12/1/1982 | 567829415 | 1 |
| 10 | Timothy | Davids | 5/27/2001 | 457891064 | 5 |

We have already tried doing this by using nested for loops, but given that we have a database consisting of 200,000 rows, the process is time consuming. Is there a way to do it by using built-in Pandas functions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `df['S/N'] = df.groupby(['FirstName', 'LastName'], sort=False).ngroup().add(1)`

Comment: Thank you very much! Could we take it one step further and set a condition that two rows are duplicates if they have the same first name, last name and either the DoB or the VAT number?